# Looping multiple videos on page and access elements inside - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have the following script which returns all `video` elements on the given page:

```
var amountWatched = '';

var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

console.log(video); // Returns HTMLCollection

for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){

   console.log(video[i]);

   video[i].addEventListener('playing', function(){
   var mytimer = setInterval(function(){

   console.log(video[i]);

   console.log(video[i].children[0].outerHTML); // Currently undefined


    }, 300);
  })
}
```

We are bascially setting up an `playing` event which will allow for us to access the `percentage` watched etc instead of having multiple scripts for multiple videos.

Now the first `console.log` returns me the following:

[image]

Which is what I would expect, I can then navigate into each entry and access the given variable that I require.

However when we are inside the `for` loop and I `console.log(video[i]);` I see the following:

[image]

Now the issue is when I try to access the `children` I get the error `undefined` my question is how can I make sure I loop the `HTMLcollection` within the `for` loop which gives me access to all elements inside of a `HTMLcollection` ?

Comment: What is purpose of `setInterval()` call within `playing` event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the playing event will happen well after the loop that adds the eventListener ... therefore `i` will equal the length of the array, therefore you're accessing an undefined array element ... simplest fix is a closure, in this case an IIFE

```
var amountWatched = '';

var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

console.log(video); // Returns HTMLCollection

for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
    (function(vid) {
        console.log(vid);
        vid.addEventListener('playing', function(){
            var mytimer = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(vid);
                console.log(vid.children[0].outerHTML); // Currently undefined
            }, 300);
        });
    })(video[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note, `timeupdate` or `progress` event can be substituted for `setInterval()` call inside of `playing` event. You are also assigning, overwriting the same `timerID` variable, `mytimer`, at each iteration where `setInterval()` is called.  How will `mytimer`  be accessible outside of IIFE closure and event handler?

Comment: @Jaromanda X this only works for one video, once one video has finished and I click another nothing happens

Comment: no errors in the console? nothing at all? I can't help if the original logic was flawed in some way - perhaps if you create a minimal complete and verifiable example I could help more